# Yarn container size and Tez container management

Tags: hadoop, hive, containers, hadoop-yarn, tez

I have a cluster with yarn resources around 15 TB. I am trying to submit a query through Hive.My default container size on yarn is 4GB. No of mappers assign for that query is around 1000. I have been assigned a total of 10 % resources in my yarn queue. So only 430 Containers will be allocated at a single point in time. Each mapper is assigned a total of 1 container. Block size on HDFS is 128 MB. How can i optmize the query.

Answer (score 0):

You've mentioned memory settings, which sound fine, so your next steps to optimize the query (since you didn't give it) are

- [Additionally tune the Tez containers](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/14309/demystify-tez-tuning-step-by-step.html)
- Make your HDFS input files be approximately the size of an HDFS block.
- Use a different queue, if yours is full. (`SET tez.queue.name`)
- Partition your Hive tables on columns that make the most sense based on your `WHERE` clauses.
- Ensure the data is stored as ORC w/ ZLib compression.
- Use LLAP, if possible